# Want to create this type of multiple Normal curve in different 'Y' axis but same 'X' axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was going through the code created by you [Multiple Normal Curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340395/producing-the-following-figure-containing-normal-distribution-and-its-rotated-v/410879#410879)... Really marvelous... Can anybody just help me in creating the figure like this?

[image]
I am confused in how to set the axes...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only interested in the Gaussians, you may consider:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
 {
 \draw[gray](0.1+1.2*\i,0) -- (4.6+1.2*\i,3);
 \draw[variable=\x,domain=-1:1,blue,thick]
  plot ({\x+1.5*\i+1},{(exp(-2*\x*\x)+\i-1)});
 \draw[gray] (1.5*\i,\i-1) -- (2+1.5*\i,\i-1);
 \draw[gray] (1+1.5*\i,\i-1) -- (1+1.5*\i,\i);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: With changing widths:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
 {
 \draw[gray](0.1+1.2*\i,0) -- (4.6+1.2*\i,3);
 \draw[variable=\x,domain=-1:1,blue,thick]
  plot ({\x+1.5*\i+1},{(exp(-(2+2*(\i-1))*\x*\x)+\i-1)});
 \draw[gray] (1.5*\i,\i-1) -- (2+1.5*\i,\i-1);
 \draw[gray] (1+1.5*\i,\i-1) -- (1+1.5*\i,\i);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @marmot for your prompt answer... Can I ask for another help? I want different means, different variances in each of these graphs... Can you please show some way how to do that?

Comment: @SandipanKarmakar Sure, if you tell me what prefactors of `\x^2` in the exponentials you want ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @marmot for your help... Let me try this by my own then I will get back to you... Thanks again...